# Use entity manager in service

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to access an entity manager in a service ?
Although I think I have to use a dependency injection, I can't find anything in the symfony documentation.
I'm using symfony 4.

Comment: What do you need the entity manager for ? If the purpose is to get a repository, you should directly inject the repository instead.

Comment: I need the entity manager to save entities to the database. That is exactly what I am going to do, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inject it into the constructor:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface

class YourService
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Thanks to autowiring no extra configuration is required.

Comment: @purplehaze For the purpose of using entity repositories, you should inject the repository directly, otherwise its a violation of the Law of Demeter, which requires to only call methods one level deeper than the current level (you shouldn't go further than calling methods on the injected EntityManager) --> Testing will be easier and your code simpler.

Comment: Ok, how can I do that ?

Comment: Given a repository called MyGreatRepository, you just inject it in the constructor just like you did for the entity manager : public function __construct(MyGreatRepository $myGreatRepository) or directly in the method if you use it only once.

Comment: @Elbarto You should exercise a certain amount of caution in recommending the injection of repositories over the entity manager.  If it is for query only then okay.  But out of the box, repositories have no persist/flush methods so updates can be challenging.  And you have to either configure the repository service manually or inherit from a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of simple class with entity manager injected, that you can register as service:

```
namespace My\AppBundle;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class YourServiceName
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagetInterface
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) : void
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

}
```

And in `services.yml`:

```
services:
    your.service.name:
        class: My\AppBundle\YourServiceName
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->manager = manager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the EntityManagerInterface to your service and check the autoWiring or you will need to inject it